# Set static DNS address in batch not working

Tags: batch

I used this script to set static DNS address but in vain. The error screenshot is attached. The network adapter is "Ethernet 4" but it shows that the script displays it as "Ethernet 4     " ??

```
Echo Check Net Connection Adapter Name
del /f /q %~dp0DHMCNetAdapter.txt>nul

wmic.exe nic where "NetConnectionStatus=2" get NetConnectionID |more 
+1>%~dp0DHMCNetAdapter.txt
REM Read the first line of a text file
set /p adapter=<%~dp0DHMCNetAdapter.txt

REM Setting Static DNS IP
set statdns=10.13.253.196
set statdns2=10.13.30.66

echo Active Network : %adapter%
Pause

rem Primary DNS Setting
netsh interface ip add dns %adapter% addr=%statdns%

rem Secondary DNS Setting
netsh interface ip add dns %adapter% addr=%statdns2%

REM Display Result of Changes
netsh interface ip show config "%adapter%"
Pause

@exit /b
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

I tested :

```
wmic.exe nic where "NetConnectionStatus=2" get NetConnectionID > file.txt
```

I find that `wmic` pads all values with blanks, apparently up to the
maximal size of the `NetConnectionID` field.

This is the source of the blanks that you get at the end of the adapter name.

For getting rid of the blanks, either find another method to get
the names, or see the post
[How to remove trailing and leading whitespace for user-provided input in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001999/how-to-remove-trailing-and-leading-whitespace-for-user-provided-input-in-a-batch)